# Pagination script last page

Tags: php, pagination

I created php script following the tutorial, but it has a mistake. It displays in the last page information which is in the previous page - it's because $perpage. How can I display only data which wasn't display yet.

EXAMPLE - If I set $perpage to 3 and I have 7 records (named 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) on page one is 1,2,3 on page two is 4,5,6 and on the last page is 5,6,7 (I want to display only record 7)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM clanek"); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

$perpage = 3; // řádků na stránku
$pages_count  = ceil($count / $perpage); //celkem stránek zaokrohleno
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$is_first = $page == 1; //první stránka
$is_last  = $page == $pages_count; 
$prev = max(1, $page - 1); 
$next = min($pages_count , $page + 1); /

$data = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum_pridani_c,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')as datumcas,nazev,kratky_popis,ID FROM clanek ORDER BY datum_pridani_c DESC LIMIT ".($page - 1).", ".$perpage);  /

while ($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

//some info her
}

if($pages_count>0) {
if(!$is_first) { 
echo '<a class="predchozistranka" href="index.php?page='.$prev.'">Předchozí</a>';
}
echo '<span class="stranka">Stránka '.$page.' / '.$pages_count.'</span>';
if(!$is_last) { 
echo '<a class="dalsistranka" href="index.php?page='.$next.'">Další</a>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum_pridani_c,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')as datumcas,nazev,kratky_popis,ID FROM clanek ORDER BY datum_pridani_c DESC LIMIT ".($page - 1).", ".$perpage);
```

It has been a while since I have used MySQL but I fired up my Workbench just now and I see that the syntax for LIMIT is LIMIT offset,rowcount. The doc says so too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

For your query to work then, instead of `($page - 1), $perpage`, it should be `($page - 1)*$perpage, $perpage`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM clanek"); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Irrelevant but the above code is highly inefficient for getting the total number of rows. It would be better if you use `SELECT count(id) FROM clanek`